# php how to get an array of files without extension in the folder

Tags: php, arrays, file, directory, scandir

I have a "path/to/folder".
What's the best method to get an array of files without file names?

I can use `$files = scandir("path/to/folder/", 1);`
but then I have to remove extensions and "." from that array.
Is there any better way to get an array of files?

**Just added:** P.S. I need the files in the "path/to/folder" without sub-folders in that folder.
So, if the files in that folder are `"ab.php, cd.php, 123.php, hello.php"`,

then the result is: `$files =array('ab', 'cd', '123', 'hello');`

Comment: just get the array file in any way you want, then use `basename()` to get the filename without the extension.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/refs.fileprocess.file.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try extending `FilesystemIterator` all you need would be :

```
echo new NoExtentionIterator(__DIR__);
```

Class Used

```
class NoExtentionIterator extends FilesystemIterator {
    public function current() {
        return pathinfo(parent::current(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    }
    public function accept() {
        return parent::current()->isfile();
    }
    public function __toString() {
        return implode("\n", iterator_to_array($this));
    }
}
```

Comment: Ordinarily, `FilterIterator` would be extended for a task like this.

Answer (score 3):

```
$files = glob('path/to/files/*.*');
foreach($files as $file) {
    $file = pathinfo($file);
    echo $file['filename'];
}
```

Or, use the [DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) class which is (much) faster.

Comment: perfect answer!